# How to get the pid of a process started using system call?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, system-calls

In a C program, in `main` I am calling a system function using `system()`.
Now I want the pid of that process started by `system()`.
Is there any way to get that pid ?

Comment: When `system(3)` returns, there is no more any (child) process. Your question makes sense only in another thread; in a single thread application, it has no sense at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and in general it's not useful.  When the call of `system()` returns to your program, the child process has terminated and been reaped, so there's no process (not even a zombie process) for it to reference.

If you need to start a process and retain its PID, you'll need to `fork()` a child yourself (noting the returned value in the parent), and in the child, `exec()` the command.  In the parent, you now have the PID, and can use it (e.g. in `waitpid()`).

Comment: These days `posix_spawn` is usually easier. http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn